# If A is an infinite set and B is at most countable set, prove that A and $A \cup B$ have the same cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove:
If A is an infinite set and B is at most countable set, prove that A and $A \cup B$ have the same cardinality.

Set definitions here are from baby Rudin.

Attempt:
There are 4 possible cases:

1.A is countable and B is finite.

2.A is countable and B is countable.

3.A is uncountable and B is finite.

4.A is uncountable and B is countable.

Then for each case I need to show that $A \cup B \sim A$. I can prove 1-3, but I am unsure how to prove case 4. And in general, it seems that my proof strategy is inefficient and there exist much faster proof then proof by cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a set $S$ to be finite iff there is a bijection from $S$ to $\{j\in \mathbb N_0:j<n\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb N_0=\mathbb N \cup \{0\}.$ It is a consequence of the Axiom of Choice (AC) that an infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

Assume (AC). Let $A$ be infinite. Let $T\subset A$ where $T$ is countably infinite. Let $B$ be countable. Let $B'=B$ \ $A.$ Then $B'$ is countable and $A\cup B=A\cup B'$ and $A \cap B'=\emptyset.$

Now $T$ and $T\cup B'$ are countably infinite. So there is a bijection $f:T\cup B'\to T.$ Extend $f$ to the domain $A\cup B'=A\cup B$ by letting $f(x)=x$ for $x\in A$ \ $T.$ Then $f:A\cup B\to A$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 3):

First prove that the union of two at most countable sets is at most countable.

Now show that any infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

Do you see how to combine these facts to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is infinite, there exists $C\subset A$ countable, since $B$ is at most countable, $C\bigcup B$ as the cardinality of $C$ so the cardinality of $A=(A-C)\bigcup C$ is the cardinality of $(A-C)\bigcup (C\bigcup B)=A\bigcup B$.

Answer (score 1):

In case 4, pick any countable subset $A' \subset A$. Then $A \cup B = (A \smallsetminus A') \cup (A' \cup B)$. Now apply case 2.